# webdriver not returning all cookies

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, session-cookies

I am trying to test a scenario where an http request is ran to login to a site using username and password and on success it redirects to google.com.It also creates session cookies of its own which I am able to view in the Firefox browser manually.

However when I am trying to retrieve all cookies using Selenium Webdriver, it is just returning the cookies that belong to the present domain.

I am using the following code:

```
Set <Cookie> allCookies=driver.manage().getCookies();
Iterator <Cookie> itr=allCookies.iterator();
APPLICATION_LOGS.info("Cookie Size--->"+driver.manage().getCookies().size());

while(itr.hasNext())
{  
    Cookie c=itr.next();
    APPLICATION_LOGS.info("Cookie Domain--->"+c.getDomain()+"Cookie Name---"+c.getName()+"Cookie Value---"+c.getValue());
}
```

Please let me know if there is any other way to retrieve all the cookies.

Comment: Is it that you were accessing, say, http://www.abc.com which redirects to http://www.google.com on some action ? so, in this case, is the driver object still referring to the original url ?

Comment: yes,its actually a loginservice something like

abc.com/login?username=abc&password=xyz&service=http://google.com , Now after this is run the http response is in the url itself and contains the token and it adds some session cookies and when I do a driver.getCurrentUrl() i get this response in the result for it.

Also I have a loginvalidate service for the above which when run redirects to google.com as well but adds some seession cookies.

However for both I am not able to retrieve the added cookies just the cookies belonging to the redirected google.com page with the above code.